gam modeling: error in variable specification
I have created this regression model that works well :
model1 = bam(depend ~ s(indep, by = gender.x,bs = "tp") + 
    s(Age, by = gender.x, bs = "tp") + ti(Age, indep, by = gender.x) +
    gender.x + 
    s(Subject, bs = "re") + s(Age, Subject, bs = "re") + 
    s(ImagingCentreCity, bs = "re"), data = M2_SRS_Project,
  method = "fREML", family = "gaussian")

but when introducing the variable timepoints:
model2 = bam(depend ~ s(Age, bs = "tp") + s(indep, bs = "tp") + 
    s(Age, indep, bs = "tp", by = gender.x) + gender.x + timepoints + 
    s(Subject, bs="re") + s(Age, Subject, bs = "fs", m = 1), 
  data = M2_SRS_Project)

the model doesn't work. The error message is as follows :
Erreur dans h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  erreur d'evaluation de l'argument 'x' lors de la selection d'une methode pour la fonction 'chol' : tableaux de tailles inadéquates

Do you have any ideas on what I can do?"
summary(M2_SRS_Project$timepoints)
BL FU1 FU2 FU3
510 162 457 509
i tried to recoded the timepoints variable

Your models aren't equivalent up to the inclusion or otherwise of the timepoints variable.
This
s(Age, indep, bs = "tp", by = gender.x)

is almost surely wrong - you do not want an isotropic smooth for an interaction between two variables. You have this right in model1 so why did you choose to do it differently in model2?
I also wouldn't do this
s(Subject, bs="re") + s(Age, Subject, bs = "fs", m = 1)

for two reasons:

using m=1 seems to be causing some issues in models that are too complex for the data they are being fitted to. It's not needed anyway as the fs smooths are fully penalized.

You are including the random intercepts for Subject twice, because they are already in the fs basis


instead, just use this in place of those two smooths:
s(Age, Subject, bs = "fs")

Maybe this helps (?) but you didn't really help yourself here; your question is confusing because the models aren't even close to be similar as you imply in the text of your question. Also, while I appreciate that you are new to SO and as such might not be aware of the Markdown formatting options, but did you look at your question (before I edited it)? It was barely legible.
